# Var value breaks on url format

Tags: php, jquery

I have an url as a var, from a div with data:

```
<div data="$firstID-$secondID-$url">
```

Then we split 'data':

```
ids = ids.split('-'); var firstID = ids[0]; var secondID = ids[1]; var url = ids[2];
```

I open it with:

```
window.open(url, 'opener');
```

That all works fine, except that the link contains all these characters, and stops at 'http://domain.com/word':

```
http://domain.com/word-word/Product/show/name-name-name-name-(name-name)/case{id-id}
```

How can I pass this insane link as var to the 'window.open' and still in tact?

Comment: Use a different separator? Maybe a comma?

Comment: Difficult: the link is an external one.

Comment: If you set it up as an array `<div data="[$firstID, $secondID ,$url]">` jQuery will do everything for you when getting the data with `data()`

Comment: I meant in the div, thus <div data="$firstID,$secondID"> Otherwise use regular expression to match urls?

Comment: Thanks Pakspul. The url gets passed but doesn't open with window.open(url, 'opener'); Any idea on that one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ids = ids.split('-');

//get rid of first 2 parts
var urlParts = ids.slice(2, ids.length)  

// join the remaining parts back
var url =  urlParts.join('-')
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This was a drag to figure out. You nailed it!